# Local Storage *Sometimes* Fails To Set or Persist Variable Between Pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, local-storage, persistent-storage

I have a simple bit of code using localStorage, it carries a running cost total over from a registration page to a payment page. This works fine for about 95 percent of users.

But sometimes the variable fails to persist to the payment page, resulting in both NULL and NAN in different instances. When this happens, developer tools will show the variable correctly set in Local Storage on the registration page (the page that sets it) but nothing at all set in Local Storage on the payment page.

I tried this in two installs of Chrome, with the same privacy settings (though not the same extensions), on separate MBPs. It worked fine in one, and failed to carry between the pages in the other.

I cannot find anything about such an inconsistent problem on Google or Stack Overflow or anywhere else. Hints?

Here's the very simple code, from the registration page:

```
    //clear local storage when loading the registration page
    function clearLocal(){
        localStorage.clear();
    }

    //calculate total
    function calculate() {

        //calculate total
        var el, i = 0;
        var total = 0;

        while(el = document.getElementsByName("class")[i++]) {
            if(el.checked) { total= total + Number(el.id);}
        }//end while

        //store total in local storage for use on payment page
        localStorage.setItem("paymentTotal",total);

    }
```

Comment: How are you getting to the next page?  Are you doing this through a `location.href` change?  An `<a>` click?  A `<form>` submission?  What is triggering the localstorage write?

Comment: Getting to the next page through a formhandler, when a "submit" button is clicked. Never had a problem with the form submitting or sending the user to the next page/payment page.

Comment: And the localStorage write is being triggered each time the JS variable is changed on the registration page, when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. The LS write is part of the same function.